# How to express the relation between two matrices (or two vectors)?

Tags: matrices, relations

If a=5 and b=12 then I can can express the relation between **a** and **b** as: a<b or b=a+7

But, if a=[2 5 17 29] and b=[2 3 30 15]

How can I express the relation between **a** and **b**?

Comment: $b=a+[0\;-2\; \;13\; -14]$

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I was asking about a general concept, how to express the relation between two matrices, vectors, sets etc.
Can I say for example that matrix a is > matrix b ?

Comment: There is no commonly used [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on $\Bbb R^4$. An example of such a total order, if you really want to use one, is the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).